# Windows phone 7 access Dropbox from application

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, dropbox

I'm developing an application for windows phone 7 and I want to access my dropbox from within this application to store files to my dropbox account. Is there a way to achieve this?

regards

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the [WP7DropBox](http://wp7dropbox.codeplex.com/) library from CodePlex to handle the standard code if you like or manually use the DropBox API yourself. There's also a general .NET library called [SharpBox](http://sharpbox.codeplex.com/).